# how to combine ranges v3 transform, join and cycle?

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

I'm trying to generate an infinite range of integers using range-v3 library. My goal is to have {0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1 ...}. 
I would like the number of times each number is repeated to be variable also. without this limitation, I can do this, and it works fine.

```
const std::vector<std::vector<int>> repvec = { {0,0,0},{1,1,1},{2,2,2} };
auto joinedVec = repvec | ranges::view::join;
auto infiniteVec = joinedVec | ranges::view::cycle;
```

But if I want the variable number of repetition, I can't make it compile:

```
int nbRep = 3;
const std::vector<int> origVec = { 0, 1, 2 };
auto repVec = origVec | ranges::view::transform( [nbRep] (const int &x) { 
    return ranges::view::repeat(x) | ranges::views::take(nbRep); 
});
auto joinedVec = repVec | ranges::view::join;
auto infiniteVec = joinedVec | ranges::view::cycle;
```

I'm not sure if it is a limitation of the ranges library or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Why the double braces for just one `vector`?  You also ought to be able to do without the intermediate variables.

Comment: @DavisHerring Agreed, it is not necessary. Fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see the reason why would you do:

```
ranges::view::repeat(x) | ranges::views::take(nbRep)
```

instead of just:

```
ranges::view::repeat_n(nbRep)
```

The solution is quite simple:

```
auto generate_range(const std::vector<int>& original, const std::size_t reps) {
    using namespace ranges; 

    auto rng = original | views::transform([reps](const auto arg) {
        return views::repeat_n(arg, reps);
    });

    return rng | views::cycle | views::join;
}
```

We first create a *range of ranges* based on the `original` vector - we *transform* its elements into *ranges* of repeated elements. We end up with a range, which elements are ranges consisting of repeated values. Based on your example, we have:

```
rng = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Now we just need to cycle all the elements. We end up with:

```
rng | cycle = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], ...]
```

Last thing we need to do is to `join` them:

```
rng | cycle | join = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...]
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <vector>

auto generate_range(const std::vector<int>& original, const std::size_t reps) {
    using namespace ranges;

    auto rng = original | views::transform([reps](const auto arg) {
        return views::repeat_n(arg, reps);
    });

    return rng | views::cycle | views::join;
}

int main() {
    using namespace ranges;

    const std::vector<int> original = {0, 1, 2};
    const int reps = 3;

    for (const auto r : generate_range(original, reps) | ranges::views::take(15)) {
        std::cout << r << ' ';
    }
}
```

which prints: `0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 1`.

Comment: It is indeed solving my problem. But I'm still wondering why swapping the cycle and the join makes it not compile. Technically, I think it should also work to do "rng | join | cycle", but it does not.

Comment: @jslap good question. I don't have an answer, but I filled an [issue](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/1401) on range-v3's repository. Let's wait for people who know.